# Semaphores, Mutex objects and Monitors

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, semaphore, monitor

As im learning more about multi-threading, common issues and good practices, it is still not crystal clear to me when and why we should use these three.

Given that all three provides mutual exclusion, which scenarios/situations implies what method to use? I know that semaphores can be used as a mutex but not vice versa and monitors
allows us to put threads in a waiting state until a certain condition is true or false.

Is there any typical good examples you can share besides the usual barber/philosophers examples?

Thanks

Comment: A simple google query: https://codegym.cc/groups/posts/220-whats-the-difference-between-a-mutex-a-monitor-and-a-semaphore

Comment: Read 'Java Concurrency in practice' by Brian Goetz. All your questions will be answered.